# Migrating from bower to yarn

Tags: migration, bower, yarnpkg

Since bower package manager is [deprecated now](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2298), I am finding a way to migrate my `bower.json` to "Yarn" without having to enter packages manually, or break dependencies.

Is there any script or utility to do the migration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've written one: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

For me running [bower-away](https://github.com/sheerun/bower-away) was enough. It took a while and some iterations until it finished, but was just follow the instructions.

As stated in the utility page just run the following commands:

```
yarn global add bower-away # or "npm install -g bower-away"
bower-away # listen and repeat!
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: do we need to update build script as well, when on last step i removed bower.json and bowerrc files I am unable to serve my project using gulp