# ENOTFOUND Package mkdirp not found or ENOTFOUND Package minimist not found

Tags: gitlab, bower, gitlab-ci

**Background:**

My web project with following `bower.json` was successfully compiled 4 months back with no modifications till date using gitlab ci pipeline (*there is no change in code since then*). Today, when i re-executed pipeline, bower started throwing *ENOTFOUND* errors as mentioned later in this question.

Errors in various run are `ENOTFOUND Package mkdirp not found` or `ENOTFOUND Package minimist not found`. How to rectify or trace source of this error maybe in terms of 3rd party package problems considering no change in bower.json and source code and also log file does not mention from which 3rd party `mkdirp or minimist` is demanded. As such, This is wired as Why would bower remove pre-existing packages from repository.

*bower.json snippet*

```
  "dependencies": {
    "editor.md": "^1.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "lunr.js": "^1.0.0",
    "reveal.js": "^3.4.1",
    "html5shiv": "^3.7.3",
    "maphilight": "^1.3.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.13.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ga-dev-tools": "git://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools.git",
    "userapp": "^2.0.0",
    "threejslib": "threejs#*",
    "threejsex": "git://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com.git",
    "mermaid": "^7.0.0",
    "respond": "^1.4.2",
    "REM-unit-polyfill": "^1.3.4",
    "modernizr": "^3.3.1",
    "data-projector": "git://github.com/datacratic/data-projector.git",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "d3": "^4.7.4",
    "normalize-css": "^6.0.0",
    "packery": "^2.1.1",
    "masonry": "^4.1.1",
    "isotope": "^3.0.3",
    "gridster": "^0.5.6",
    "jquery.shapeshift": "^2.0.0",
    "shufflejs": "^4.1.1",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.3",
    "github-fork-ribbon-css": "^0.2.1",
    "prefixfree": "*",
    "jquery.balloon.js": "git://github.com/urin/jquery.balloon.js.git#1.0.3",
    "qtip2": "^2.2.1",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.1",
    "draggabilly": "^2.1.1",
    "fabric": "^1.7.13"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "mermaid": "~7.0.0",
    "normalize-css": "~6.0.0",
    "lunr.js": "^1.0.0",
    "gridster": "^0.7.0",
    "prefixfree": "^1.0.10"
  }
```

*Error Log (Last Line)*

$ bower install --allow-root

```
bower ga-dev-tools#*        not-cached git://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools.git#*
bower ga-dev-tools#*           resolve git://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools.git#*
bower threejsex#*           not-cached git://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com.git#*
bower threejsex#*              resolve git://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com.git#*
bower data-projector#*      not-cached git://github.com/datacratic/data-projector.git#*
bower data-projector#*         resolve git://github.com/datacratic/data-projector.git#*
bower jquery.balloon.js#1.0.3       not-cached git://github.com/urin/jquery.balloon.js.git#1.0.3
bower jquery.balloon.js#1.0.3          resolve git://github.com/urin/jquery.balloon.js.git#1.0.3
bower jquery#^3.2.1                 not-cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#^3.2.1
bower jquery#^3.2.1                    resolve https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#^3.2.1
bower lunr.js#^1.0.0                not-cached https://github.com/olivernn/lunr.js.git#^1.0.0
.
.
.
bower threejslib#*                          progress received 95.6MB of 220.2MB downloaded, 43%
bower threejslib#*                          progress received 103.0MB of 220.2MB downloaded, 47%
bower threejslib#*                          progress received 107.1MB of 220.2MB downloaded, 49%
bower threejslib#*                          progress received 111.4MB of 220.2MB downloaded, 51%
bower threejslib#*                          progress received 114.9MB of 220.2MB downloaded, 52%
bower threejslib#*                          progress received 119.2MB of 220.2MB downloaded, 54%
bower threejslib#*                          progress received 123.8MB of 220.2MB downloaded, 56%
bower threejslib#*                          progress received 128.6MB of 220.2MB downloaded, 58%
bower threejslib#*                          progress received 132.7MB of 220.2MB downloaded, 60%
bower threejslib#*                          progress received 138.0MB of 220.2MB downloaded, 63%
bower threejslib#*                          progress received 143.6MB of 220.2MB downloaded, 65%
bower mkdirp#^0.5.1                        ENOTFOUND Package mkdirp not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up with random `ENOTFOUND Package * not found` errors for very long and display of package names even am not aware of or searchable in google like package `ENOTFOUND Package which not found`.

Thereafter came across [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/yarn-package-manager-an-improvement-over-npm#toc-installing-yarn) article which referred to [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com) as **better replacement to NPM and Bower**. Thus i've used [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728053/migrating-from-bower-to-yarn) to migrate my project from npm/bower to yarn and **errors are gone**.

Code used for same after installation of yarn is: *(it needs previous copy of bower_components folder to exist with node_modules)*

```
npm install -g bower-away
bower-away --diff
bower-away --apply
rmdir /s /q bower_components
bower-away
yarn install
```